# Form based authentication configuration issue

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, authentication

I am using form based authentication in a java maven web project that I am building. The application is deployed to a tomcat web server, so I added a few users to the users file. When I try to access a protected resource, I get the login page, as expected. However, when I enter the credentials, I am taken to the form-error page. Is that usually indicative of the user not being correctly declared in the tomcat-users.xml file? I also have declared a 403 error page, so that I can distinguish between an authentication and an authorization issue. My tomcat-users file is pretty thin, but looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="administrator"/>
    <user username="bill" password="billpw" roles="administrator"/>
  </tomcat-users>
```

I am trying to login with bill, and I'm not sure what the problem is. Any ideas what could be going on? I've tried resetting the server, no luck.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SecureAC</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/admin/sec.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SecureAC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/sec</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/login/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/login/login-error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Administrative Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>
            CONFIDENTIAL
        </transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint> 
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>employee</role-name>
</security-role>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/403error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: How are you comparing the username/pass from the tomcat-users.xml file from the tomcat server in your form? Is tomcat giving you access to tomcat-users.xml file from a web application?

Comment: Is this approach correct? Can you not use a database to store the username and passwords instead of using tomcat-users.xml?

Comment: I have access to the tomcat server, it's installed on the same laptop im developing on, so I just opened the tomcat-users file to look at the usernames/passwords. This is for a class, but I agree, in a real environment, the usernames and passwords would come from a database.

Comment: <form-error-page> corresponds to login failed. Because you are getting the login screen and are able to enter the username/password, the config seems to be correct. I am not sure why you are not getting logged in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382159/tomcat-7-form-based-authentification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979593/basic-auth-with-tomcat-not-working

Comment: Show us your `web.xml`.